# Computed property on partial POCO class prevent linq query on DbContext

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5, partial-classes

Using EF 5.0 (aka 4.3) **I transformed one of my pocos** (which I got from reverse engeniring my database), **to be a partial class** in order **to extend it with a computed propertry** wich is not relevant in my DB but is in my application.

Though, when I'm querying the poco via the DBContext,

```
var Categories = context.CATEGORY.ToList();
```

It throw an **System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException** saying : **"Invalid column name 'Computed_property'."**. Because of course 'Computed_property' doesn't exist in the db.

So I was wondering, is there a hint or an attribute that could be used on the property to avoid this problem ? Something like

```
[IgnorePropertyInDB]
```

Thx for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is `[NotMapped]` attribute for this purpose.

Comment: Thank you Ladislav, once again I owe you.